# Wrong item selected in list

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, listactivity, simpleadapter

I have a ListActivity with SimpleAdapter to display a 2 item list using the simple_items_list_2 layout. An ArrayList of HashMap holds the items.

The list has to hold data i receive as UDP packets from different. So, I have another thread, in which these packets are received. From there, using a handler, it sends the received data, and adds the items to the list.

Now I receive the packets properly, even the list is generated. However, when i select say item B, it selects item A sometimes.

Here are the code snippets:

In the OnCreate() ,

```
        lv = getListView();

        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        String[] from = { "name", "address" };
        int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

In the handler's code after it gets a message with the contents from the thread :

```
        list.add(putData(scanned_name, scanned_addr));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) { 

                TextView name_tv = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                TextView addr_tv = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

                selectedName = name_tv.getText().toString();
                selectedAddr = addr_tv.getText().toString();
```

The HashMap function to put data:

```
private HashMap<String, String> putData(String name, String address) {
        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item.put("name", name);
        item.put("address", address);
        return item;
    }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `view.findViewById`

```
TextView name_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
TextView addr_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
```

Comment: Yes it seems to work From what I understand, in my code the TextView i got was the first in the list and adding view makes it the TextView of the item clicked?

Comment: yes, when you click an item, **onItemClick** event is raised and the item's view is passed as one of the parameter. So use that view to read name and address